# Изменение размера textarea из-за FORM

Tags: post, form, javascript

Скажите, пожалуйста. Почему изменяется размер области textarea при использовании `<form>`?
Нужно, чтобы область не сдвигалась.

Вот скриншот. На нём не используется `<form>`. Рамка выглядит как нужно.

[image]

```
<textarea name="smile"></textarea>
```

Применяю `<form>` и рамка сдвигается вверх.

[image]

```
<form method="POST" name="chatform">
<textarea name="smile"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в css:

```
form {
    display: block; /* inline-block/inline */
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. inline выручил.

Comment: @Nikita Shpak, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @lampa сделал. Извините, на сайте первый день. Еще не со всеми тонкостями разобрался.